# Setting button text after it's been added to navigation bar in sencha touch 2

Tags: button, view, sencha-touch-2, navigationbar

I am trying to change the text on a button after it's been added to navigationbar in the initialize method of the view. When debugging with Chrome however, it stops and gives the following message on Connection.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined. I thought this should be simple and am a bit confused! Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('EventsTest.view.NavTest', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    config: {
        navigationBar: {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Help',
                    id: 'favoritesHelp',
                    translate: true,
                    translationKey: 'navigationbar.helpbutton',
                    align: 'right'
                }
            ]
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula tincidunt purus, a dignissim dui rutrum ut. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam pellentesque quam non orci porta sodales. Nulla laoreet varius libero, ac eleifend velit eleifend et. Proin a odio orci, sed bibendum libero. Maecenas eget nisl nec sapien sollicitudin mollis. Phasellus vel est eget risus ornare facilisis ac sed dui. Aliquam non feugiat sapien. In suscipit libero nec lorem lobortis molestie.'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'nextPage',
                        text: 'Next Page'
                    }
                ]

            }

        ]
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.setDefaultBackButtonText('reverse');
        var helpBtn = this.getNavigationBar().query('#favoritesHelp');
        helpBtn.text = 'Yello';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your query is wrong. Try replace this 2 line:

```
var helpBtn = this.getNavigationBar().query('#favoritesHelp');
helpBtn.text = 'Yello';
```

with this:

```
var helpBtn = Ext.getCmp('favoritesHelp');
helpBtn.setText("Yellow");
```

Hope it helps :)

---

**EDIT:**

It's ok to keep your query like that but you need to remember that your query will retrieve an array of elements not a single element.

Besides that, you cannot change your text inside your button by using `.text` since it will not change the `innerHTML` of your button. Try using this:

```
var helpBtn = this.getNavigationBar().query('#favoritesHelp');
helpBtn[0].textElement.dom.innerHTML = "Yellow";
```

Comment: The query is definitely correct. The `Ext.getCmp()` function is just another convenient function for `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`. I have double checked in the debugger as well. After the `var helpBtn = this.getNavigationBar().query('#favoritesHelp');` statement it does fetch the proper component.

Comment: Thanks. After stepping through with the debugger, I realized that the `.query()` function always returns an array even in the case of only 1 component being selected. I was able to access it like so: `this.getNavigationBar().query('#favoritesHelp')[0].setHtml();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want....

```
config: {
        listeners: {
                   initialize: function(){
                   this.down('button').setText('Whatever You Want')
        }
}}
```

Comment: this does not work, I've tried adding this listeners object to the config object and the navigationbar object with no luck. Either case still returns the readyState error.